# How can I check file integrity after the file is converted?

Tags: c#, azure, checksum, data-integrity

I am new in data integrity check. I have an application which handles retrieving PDF data from database and save locally. Afterwards, the app need convert the PDF file into PNG pages and upload the PNG pages as stream up to Cloud. My question is if it is feasible to create an integrity check (checksum) during this download and upload process to make sure the app is uploading the correct and intact pages from the original PDF file? The reason I ask is we had corrupted document in Cloud and the file pulled from database was fine. I am looking for causes and no matter what the bug could be. I prefer I can have a guard on site to verify the PNGs before uploading. I am using C#. Thanks.

Comment: Checksum is irrelevant, you need to check results of the PDF->PNG conversion (which is one-way, hence, not a trivial task).

Comment: You could read the converted image and check the header to know if it's a valid png file

Comment: @SniperLegacy The corrupted document had one page coming from the other irrelevant document which happened to be processed almost the same time.